# Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $h(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent in BASIC probability -- can we use double integration?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, independence

In advanced probability we can just say:

\begin{align}
& P(h(X) \in A, g(Y) \in B) \\[6pt]
= {} & P(X \in h^{-1}(A), Y \in g^{-1}(B)) \\[6pt]
= {} & P(X \in h^{-1}(A)) P(Y \in g^{-1}(B)) \\[6pt]
= {}& P(h(X) \in A) P(g(Y) \in B)
\end{align}

where $X,Y \in (\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$ and are $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B(\mathbb R))$-valued, $A,B$ are Borel and $h,g$ are some kinds of functions (Borel? Bounded and Borel? $\mathscr F$-measurable?)

---

**But what about in basic probability? Is there a double integral way to approach this?**

---

The hint given is to show that

$$P(h(X) \in (-\infty, a], g(Y) \in (-\infty, b])$$

$$ = P(h(X) \in (-\infty, a]) P(g(Y) \in (-\infty, b])$$

I can sort of use the same argument as in advanced probability but then I would have to use

$$h^{-1}(-\infty, a]$$

Is that acceptable to use in basic probability?

I think

$$h^{-1}(-\infty, a] = \{x \mid h(x) \in (-\infty, a]\}$$

So $$X \in h^{-1}(-\infty, a] = \operatorname{Range}(X) \cap \{x \mid h(x) \in (-\infty, a]\} = \{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \in \{x \mid h(x) \in (-\infty, a]\}\}$$

Regardless, I think $X$ and $Y$ are <strike>absolutely continuous</strike> continuous with pdfs.

I think there should be a double integral way to approach this.

---

Edit 4.5 years later: by the way, what's the condition for $h$ and $g$ to do this please? See here: [Prove that for independent random variables $X_i$, we have $f_i(X_i)$ are independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944284/prove-that-for-independent-random-variables-x-i-we-have-f-ix-i-are-indepe)

Comment: I wonder if your "advanced" argument only _looks_ advanced because of al the notation? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy function inverse of an interval is acceptable? Prerequisite for the class is only calc I and II

Comment: Actually the "advanced" part is just the stuff about Borel sets.  With students who haven't had that, if you instead just say "sets", they probably won't suspect a thing.  You can say $f^{-1}(A) = \{ x : f(x)\in A\}$.   If they haven't seen that before, I suppose it should be introduced. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy is there perhaps a double integral way to go about this?

Comment: @MichaelHardy by the way, what's the condition for $h$ and $g$ to do this please? See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944284/prove-that-for-independent-random-variables-x-i-we-have-f-ix-i-are-indepe